# Misma columna en clave primaria y en relación

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Tengo la clase Rubro mapeada de la siguiente manera y estoy en un proceso de migración de [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) **3.3.1** a **5.2.7.Final** y de [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) **2.5.6** a **4.3.1.Release**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="ar.com.vgmsistemas.dto">
<class name="Rubro" table="segmento">
    <composite-id class="PkRubro" name="id" unsaved-value="undefined">
        <key-property name="idNegocio" column="id_negocio"></key-property>
        <key-property name="idRubro" column="id_segmento"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property column="de_segmento" name="descripcion" type="string" />
    <many-to-one class="Negocio" name="negocio" column="id_negocio" insert="false" update="false" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

El problema es que tengo el `id_negocio` tanto en la clave primaria de rubro como en la de negocio, en las versiones anteriores funciona correctamente pero ahora me tira el siguiente error:

> MappingException: Error calling Value#setTypeUsingReflection:
>       containingClassName=[ar.com.vgmsistemas.dto.PkRubro], propertyName=[idNegocio],
>       role=[ar.com.vgmsistemas.dto.Rubro.id.idNegocio]: 
>       origin(com/ar/vgmsistemas/dto/mapping/Rubro.hbm.xml)

Comment: Añade el código la clase Rubro y PKRubro